# Need list of cancelled/voided/deleted transactions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have an ETL set up to pull SalesReceipts, Invoices, and CreditMemos into our own data warehouse. However, if a transaction in the past has been voided/deleted this will cause our numbers to be off. I have not found a way to get a list of invalidated transactions and I'd prefer not to have to pull all transactions for all time for each invocation of the ETL.

More details:
Our data is in QBO and I am using the Java API provided by Intuit.

I have reviewed the API (both the online endpoint API as well as the Java API) and I have not found much to work with.

Here is an example of a query for Invoice data:

```
<page loop>
{
    Invoice invoice = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(Invoice.class);
    String query = select($(invoice)).skip(page * PAGE_SIZE).take(PAGE_SIZE).generate();
    QueryResult result = dataService.executeQuery(query);
    for (IEntity entity : result.getEntities())
    {
        Transaction t = (Transaction) entity;
        System.out.println(t.getStatus());
    }
}
```

However I never encounter any of our cancelled/voided/deleted transactions with this query and the transaction status may not be used in the where filter.

EDIT #2
I believe I have found what I need in the Change Data Capture service.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00600_changedata_operation

Some code:

```
List<IEntity> entities = new ArrayList();
entities.add(new SalesReceipt());
entities.add(new Invoice());
entities.add(new CreditMemo());
List<CDCQueryResult> cresult = dataService.executeCDCQuery(entities, "2011-12-01T00:00:00Z");
...
```

This will return all transactions that have changed (modified, added, deleted) since the date specified, though what's VERY odd to me is that if I use the date string "2011-12-01T0:0:0Z" I get only transactions with the DELETED state.

For reference:
"2011-12-01T00:00:00Z": all added, modified, deleted transactions.
"2011-12-01T0:0:0Z": only deleted transactions.

Thanks

Comment: Is this for QuickBooks for WINDOWS, or QuickBooks ONLINE? What API are you using? You need to provide more details...

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue with only getting deleted records when I include the timezone.   I am getting correct results by dropping the timezone in the time string and making sure the results are in local (to intuit) pacific standard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preston,
If you are using QuickBooks Desktop you need to use the QBXML SDK v13 to access transactions, if you are using QuickBooks Online you can use QBO v3 REST API.

QBO:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services

QBD:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb

regards,
Jarred