# Determine if a Customer in the CDC response has been Deleted

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We are using the [IntuitCDCResponse](https://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/html/a5392328-bf3d-37c6-84de-de9ac1fe94ce.htm) class of the .Net SDK for QuickBooks Online to retrieve a list of customer entitities that have changed within a specified period of time.

Currently, we are able to retrieve the list of changed customers and iterate the list. From this point, **how can we tell whether or not the customer has been deleted in QuickBooks Online?**

The [docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/changedatacapture) say that when the entity has been deleted, the `status` of the entity is set to `Deleted`. We are assuming that this status is passed on to the `status` property of the [`Customer`](https://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/html/69641f4e-9c02-81cc-2f1c-70e1d8d70137.htm) class in the SDK.

Here is the code we are currently attempting to use to determine if the Customer has been deleted.

```
if (customer.statusSpecified && customer.status == EntityStatusEnum.Deleted)
{
    // handle deletion event locally
}
```

As it is, all Customer objects always have a `statusSpecified` value of false and the `status` value is always `EntityStatusEnum.Deleted`, regardless of whether or not this is actually the case. We have repeatedly tested customers that have been updated, created and/or deleted.

We did attempt to search the [SDK source code](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-DotNET-SDK) for hints about how the Customer class is being initialized, however it appears that the Intuit.IPP.Data namespace is not available in the source code.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386048/need-list-of-cancelled-voided-deleted-transactions) is similar, and of some interest, but does not discuss *how* to correctly determine if the Customer has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best **workaround** I could come up with for now.

```
if ( (customer.statusSpecified && customer.status == EntityStatusEnum.Deleted)
    || customer.DisplayName.Contains("(deleted)") )
{
    // handle deletion event locally
}
```

Or if you'd prefer to give up hope entirely of being able to determine the delete status the correct way...

```
if ( customer.DisplayName.Contains("(deleted)") )
{
    // handle deletion event locally
}
```

QuickBooks Online appends the term "(deleted)" to the end of the Display Name when you mark a customer as inactive. This [QuickBooks Help article](https://community.intuit.com/articles/1146137-deleting-and-restoring-customers) is the closest I could come to documentation of this behavior. Under the section "To restore a customer" it states:

> inactive customer will be noted as (deleted)

Answer (score 0):

[EntityStatusEnum Enumeration](https://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/html/2843973a-bd5e-8c06-e054-d243297154a8.htm)

EntityStatusEnum is not a true or false value, it is an enumeration value 0-6. I recommend changing the `customer.status` value to an int, where 0-6 represents the documentations values respectively.

Edit:

`EntityStatusEnum.Deleted` is going to return `0`

and

`customer.status` is going to return `true` or `false`

Comment: I believe you are mistaken about `customer.status`. The `status` property is inherited from the [IntuitEntity](https://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/html/f7380e23-d1a8-6520-de89-1b928bbb1d80.htm) class and shows a data type of `EntityStatusEnum`. So a comparison of `customer.status` to `EntityStatusEnum.Deleted` is an acceptable expression.

Comment: What about `customer.statusSpecified`? I think the if statement is wrong. Shouldn't it be: `customer.statusSpecified == true && customer.status == EntityStatusEnum.Deleted` @RichC

Comment: [Double-checked](https://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/html/d879bbdf-d1f3-7054-3945-798de11b7fb9.htm) `customer.statusSpecified`. It's data type is `bool`. Also, `customer.statusSpecified` and `customer.statusSpecified == true` both yield the same boolean result and are acceptable expressions. The `if` statement should be correct.